# problem with closures while creating memoize function

Tags: javascript, closures

I was trying to implement memoize function in JS.
I have written a function by myself.

But it is not working, I don't know the reason why `cache` variable is getting cleared on every call.

```
function calcF(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

function memoize(cb) {
  let cache = {};
  return function () {
    const arg = arguments[0];
    console.log(cache); // getting empty object always
    if (cache[arg]) {
      return cache[arg];
    } else {
      const res = cb(arg);
      cache[arg] = res;
      return res;
    }
  };
}

function fib(n) {
  const m = memoize(calcF);
  return m(n);
}

console.time();
console.log(fib(10));
console.timeEnd();
```

When I move `let cache={}` outside of the function, then program is working fine.

If any can explain me what I am missing here, the it will be a really great help.

Answer (score 0):

Because every call to `fib` calls `memoize(calcF)` again, which creates a new cache. Each memoised function is called only a single time in the line `m(n)`.

You should write just

```
const fib = memoize(calcF);
```

or (unnecessarily)

```
const m = memoize(calcF);
function fib(n) {
  return m(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found out the issue with my code.
There are other plenty of good options available out there. But I wanted to try it from my own. So sharing the issues and the final solution here:

There were three issues in above code:

1. I was calling `fib` inside `calcF` instead for calling `calcF` itself.
2. The issue @Bergi pointed out, that I was creating new instance of `memoize`.
3. I wasn't passing `cache` in `calcF`.

function calcF(n, cache) {

```
  if (n === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }

  let l, r;

  if (cache[n - 1]) {
    l = cache[n - 1];
  } else {
    const res = calcF(n - 1, cache);
    cache[n - 1] = res;
    l = res;
  }

  if (cache[n - 2]) {
    r = cache[n - 2];
  } else {
    const res = calcF(n - 2, cache);
    cache[n - 2] = res;
    r = res;
  }

  return l + r;
}

function memoize(cb) {
  let cache = {};
  return function () {
    const arg = arguments[0];
    // getting empty object always
    if (cache[arg]) {
      return cache[arg];
    } else {
      const res = cb(arg, cache);
      cache[arg] = res;
      return res;
    }
  };
}

const m = memoize(calcF);

function fib(n) {
  return m(n);
}

console.time();
console.log(fib(6));
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
console.log(fib(61));
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
console.log(fib(100));
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
console.log(fib(102));
console.timeEnd();
```